# Array retrieval from JSON file

Tags: json, jackson

I have an array in JSON file which look like this

```
{ "fields": [
        {
            "name": "order_id",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "district_id",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "position": 1
        }]
}
```

I'm using a TREE MODEL in retrieving the contents of the array "fields" and my code looks like this ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
File jsonFile = new File("metadata.json");
String theJsonString = jsonFile.toString();
String name = null;
String type =null;
int position = 0;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(theJsonString);
JsonNode fields = rootNode.get("fields");
    if (fields != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i ++) {
        if(fields.has("name"))
            name = fields.get("name").getTextValue();
        if(fields.has("type"))
             type = fields.get("type").getTextValue();
        if(fields.has("position"))  
             position = fields.get("position").getIntValue();


        System.out.println(name);
    }
    }
  }
```

I get the following error during the run time ::

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3eed2cab; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._skipComment(ReaderBasedParser.java:1498)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedParser.java:1474)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2761)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2709)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1533)
    at metadata.JSONParser.main(JSONParser.java:32)
```

I have just started working with JSON and hence unable to find a solution. Could anybody help me resolve this?

Comment: it says line 1 column 2, which would be the space after {... you could try removing it and see if that affects the error? It shouldn't cause a problem as it's valid JSON but you never know

Comment: its is valid JSON file !

Comment: yes I said it's valid. I checked it myself on JsonLint.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the contents of the file `metadata.json` then calling `toString` on the file will not give you that. Instead it will give you a string which holds the path to the filename.

Instead create a `FileInputStream` from the `File` like so:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jsonFile);
```

The you can use it with the `mapper`

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(fis);
```

You might also want to call `fields.get(i)` when you are iterating through the array to access each `JsonNode` contained in the array.

Comment: hey thanks alot ... i'm done with it ... but it isn't enough if we add fields.get(i); it should be like this   JsonNode field = fields.get(i);

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I fixed the problem finally by this code to get the JsonParser object.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
JsonParser jp = new JsonFactory().createParser(fis);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days ago. **My JSON** have the next syntax:

```
{ "boxes": [
  {
    "name": "redBox.png",
    "version": 15
  },
  {
    "name": "blueBox.png",
    "version": 9
  }
]
}
```

I had to create **method which return me POJO classes** with box versions. My solution is follow:

```
private static List<DataVersion> receiveDataVersions() throws IOException
    {
        String path = System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + File.separator +
                        "versions.json";
        List<DataVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonNode folder = null;
        try( InputStream stream = new FileInputStream( path ) )
        {
            folder = new ObjectMapper().readTree( stream );
        }
        JsonNode boxes = folder.get( "inst" );
        boxes.forEach( version -> versions.add( new DataVersion(
                        version.get( "name" ).getTextValue(),
                        version.get( "version" ).getIntValue() ) ) );
        return versions;
    }
```

POJO is as follows:

```
public class DataVersion
{
    private String name;
    private int version;

    public DataVersion() {
    }

    public DataVersion(String name, int version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version){
        this.version=version;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "DataVersion [" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", version=" +
                        version + ']';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in your code

```
jsonFactory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS);
```